# Laravel blade template (Undefined class Meta) error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I’m getting error  “Undefined class Meta” on my laravel blog application. Also it doesn't provides the title on output. On html output I get blank . Is it problem because of  Undefined class Meta? If then how can I define that class on blade engine? Any idea?

Check screen shot to understand

[image]

Comment: Try using the full namespace of Meta.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, Laravel does not have Meta class by default. Are you using same package? (e.g. eusonlito/laravel-Meta)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't installed the package but you're trying to use it.

First, type `composer require eusonlito/laravel-meta`

Then, in your `config/app.php` add:

```
'providers' => [
    '...',
    Eusonlito\LaravelMeta\MetaServiceProvider::class
];

'aliases' => [
    '...',
    'Meta'    => Eusonlito\LaravelMeta\Facade::class,
];
```

Then retry. Your app should work